# Cloudflare SSL для поддомена

Tags: ssl, cloudflare

Сайт подключен к Cloudflare, как можно подключить SSL к поддомену?

Answer (score 0):

Нет вообще никаких проблем.

Генерируете сертификаты на странице [https://www.cloudflare.com/a/crypto/ваш-сайт](https://www.cloudflare.com/a/crypto/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%88-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82) (для перехода туда нажмите на Crypto). Далее в строке "Origin Certificates" нажмите кнопку "Create Certificate". Получите бесплатный сертификат на основной домен и все поддомены - в виде двух файлов: .pem и .key.

Дальше эти сертификаты надо разместить на вашем сервере nginx и apache согласно инструкциям в самом низу той же страницы, где вы будете копировать текст .pem и .key